# Stability of crystal and crystal-less oscillator transmitters

Tags: oscillator, crystal, transmitter, stability, fsk

I have stumbled upon this very cheap so called "crystal-less" RF transmitter:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/368/Si4012-35123.pdf

It says there on page 5 the Carrier Frequency Accuracy is 250 ppm while crystal-less. Does this mean that for a 433 MHz carrier there will be 250 x 433 =

108.25 kHz

maximum drift above or below the nominal carrier frequency ? Does this look like enough for the FSK receiver not to be able to tell the signal any longer ? A few tips on how to program the receiver and whether or not I can get away with a non-crystal-less SiLabs paired receiver would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, according to the data sheet and using their ppm figures the actual frequency of 433 MHz could be out by up to 108.25 kHz.

> Does this look like enough for the FSK receiver not to be able to tell
>   the signal any longer ?

No, I think a reasonably well designed FSK receiver should be able to lock on to anything in the realm of 433 MHz +/- 1 MHz. The FM demodulator should be designed to exceed the full range of the oscillator offset plus the FM deviation. I don't see this as difficult. Then you have a data slicer after the demodulator and you should be fine.

Remember that the drift is slow moving and a data slicer's speed at traversing across the full receiver demodulated output range will be many, many times faster.

> A few tips on how to program the receiver

I have no idea what you mean.

> whether or not I can get away with a non-crystal-less SiLabs paired
>   receiver would help

"non-crystal-less" - what are you actually asking here?

Comment: I am talking about regular receivers that do not have the SiLabs patented "crystal-less" technology. Those regular receivers will usually have quite high drifts, in the realm of 10 000 ppm if I am not mistaken (can be brought to 10 ppm with external crystal though). Programming them as in setting their params via SPI / I2C / whatever interface they are using. I am not looking to actually design the receiver :)

Comment: I read your comment but I'm not sure what relevance this have. Is there something about the answer that confuses you or, do you need additional info in my answer?